scrape the html page after click on a div tag using BeautifulSoup
I got some troubles when scraping the questions and answers from websites:
https://tech12h.com/bai-hoc/trac-nghiem-lich-su-12-bai-1-su-hinh-thanh-trat-tu-gioi-moi-sau-chien-tranh-gioi-thu-hai
The problem is the answer only appear when I click on a div Xem đáp án (scroll down to the end) but it's not a link, it just a div, I guess it use Javascript event trigger to render content after the click on div.
How can I deal with this with Beautifulsoup. I got confict driver problem with Selenium when I use on Ubuntu.
Thank you

If the website is dependent on Javascript then you're unlikley to be able to achieve your objective with BeautifulSoup. Persevere with Selenium - i.e., try to figure out why it's not working on your platform

@SIGHUP yes, you're right

You shouldn't need to explicitly download a Chrome driver. Modern selenium versions handle it for you.
Hence, all you need is this:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement import WebElement
from collections.abc import Iterable

OPTIONS = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
OPTIONS.add_argument("--headless=true")

URL = "https://tech12h.com/bai-hoc/trac-nghiem-lich-su-12-bai-1-su-hinh-thanh-trat-tu-gioi-moi-sau-chien-tranh-gioi-thu-hai"

CSS_P = "#accordionExample > p"
CSS_L = "#accordionExample > ul li"

def etext(e: WebElement) -> str:
    if t := e.text:
        return t.strip()
    p = e.get_property("textContent")
    if isinstance(p, str):
        return p.strip()
    return ""

def get_common(driver: webdriver.Chrome, css: str) -> Iterable[str]:
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    ec = EC.presence_of_all_elements_located
    selector = By.CSS_SELECTOR, css
    yield from map(etext, wait.until(ec(selector)))

def chunks(items: list[str], chunk=4) -> Iterable[list[str]]:
    for i in range(0, len(items), chunk):
        yield items[i : i + chunk]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with webdriver.Chrome(OPTIONS) as driver:
        driver.get(URL)
        questions = list(get_common(driver, CSS_P))
        answers = list(get_common(driver, CSS_L))
        assert len(questions) * 4 == len(answers)
        qanda = dict(zip(questions, chunks(answers)))
        for k, v in qanda.items():
            print(k)
            for a in v:
                print(f"\t{a}")

Output (partial):
Câu 1: Để kết thúc nhanh chiến tranh ở châu Âu và châu Á - Thái Bình - Dương, ba cường quốc đã thống nhất mục đích gì?
        A. Sử dụng bom nguyên tử để tiêu diệt phát xít Nhật.
        B. Hồng quân Liên Xô nhanh chóng tấn công vào tận sào huyệt của phát xít Đức ở Bec-lin.
        C. Tiêu diệt tận gốc chủ nghĩa phát xít Đức và quân phiệt Nhật.
        D. Tất cả các mục đích trên.
Câu 2: Sự kiện nào dẫn đến thành lập nước Cộng hòa Liên bang Đức?
        A. Nước Đức được hòan toàn thống nhất.
        B. Nước Đức đã tiêu diệt tận gốc chủ nghĩa phát xít.
        C. Mĩ, Anh, Pháp hợp nhất các vùng chiếm đóng.
        D. Tất cả các sự kiện trên.


Aw Thank you. But are you sure it works on  Ubuntu? As I have been struggling with this for a while. Because I already put the match driver into the folder so your code works, but not sure if it still before that. I'm pretty sure I did driver = webdriver.Chrome() earlier and it raised a lot of error :)

@Dinasour I cannot guarantee that this will work on Ubuntu (I'm on MacOS) but I believe it should work. Maybe others can comment

Thank you... (:

I finally solved this issue!
I couldn't run the driver due to a conflict between the chrome app version and the chrome-driver version (the one located in usr/local/bin).
I found this repository containing my chrome app version: https://github.com/dreamshao/chromedriver
I download the suitable version for me and put in the usr/local/bin folder.
